# what is the toString parameter?

Tags: javascript, arguments, tostring

By looking at source code, I stumble upon `toString()` quite frequently. I know this is used to convert some object into a `String` object. However, all got lost when I saw this `toString(16)`. What is the argument/parameter for? I tried searching other sites, but they didn't display this parameter/argument. I need a detailed answer explaining what difference does it make in the string, if there is any difference.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Comment: You should post the exact code involved, because strictly speaking the parameter could mean *anything*.

Comment: [MDN `Number.toString([radix])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular implementation of `.toString()` can do whatever it wants with the parameter, but for example the `Number` version interprets a numeric argument as being the base to be used for the string representation of a numeric value.

Thus

```
alert(new Number(27).toString(16)); // alerts "1b"
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, every object has a `object.toString()` method when the object is to be represented as a text value.

The `Number.toString([radix])` method accepts the [radix] parameter which specifies the base to use for representing the number.